# Subtraction of counts of 2 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 different tables, A and B. A is something like `created` and b is `removed`

I want to obtain the nett difference of the counts per week in an SQL query.

Currently I have

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', TIMESTAMP AT time ZONE '+08') AS Week,
       Count(id) AS "A - New"
FROM table_name.A
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

This gets me the `count per week` for table A only. How could I incorporate the logic of subtracting the same `Count(id)` from B, for the same timeframe?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Your query looks like PostgreSQL, not SQL-Server. Can you confirm which db vendor this question is for please?

Comment: @Used_By_Already Sorry for the wrong tag, I'm querying via Redash.io, should be postgres!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The potential issue here is that for any week you might only have additions or removals, so to align a count from the 2 tables - by week - an approach would be to use a full outer join, like this:

```
SELECT COALESECE(A.week, b.week) as week
     , count_a
     , count_b
     , COALESECE(count_a,0) - COALESECE(count_b,0) net
FROM (
    SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', TIMESTAMP AT time ZONE '+08') AS week
         , Count(*) AS count_A
    FROM table_a
    GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('week', TIMESTAMP AT time ZONE '+08')
    ) a
FUUL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', TIMESTAMP AT time ZONE '+08') AS week
         , Count(*) AS count_b
    FROM table_b
    GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('week', TIMESTAMP AT time ZONE '+08')
    ) b on a.week = b.week
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply! i get `Error running query: column "team_created.timestamp" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: So sorry, I forgot the GROUP BY clauses in both subqueries. I added them back. Note you used "group by 1" but I'm not fond of using column position as a reference, so my chosen syntax may look a little harder, but it is will have exactly the same execution plan.

Comment: Good answer. You can replace the `ON` clause with a `USING` clause, i.e. `on a.week = b.week` by `using (week)` and thus get rid of the clumsy `COALESECE(A.week, b.week) as week` which you can then replace by `week` only.

Answer (score 0):

The usual syntex for substracting values from 2 queries is as follows

```
Select (Query1) - (Query2) from dual;
```

Assuming both the tables have same number of id in 'id' column and your given query works for tableA, following query will subtract the count(id) from both tables.

```
select(SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', TIMESTAMP AT time ZONE '+08') AS Week,
   Count(id) AS "A - New" FROM table_name.A GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1) - (SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', TIMESTAMP AT time ZONE '+08') AS Week,
   Count(id) AS "B - New" FROM table_name.B GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1) from dual
```

Or you can also try the following approach

```
Select c1-c2 from(Query1 count()as c1),(Query2 count() as c2);
```

So your query will be like

```
Select c1-c2 from (SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', TIMESTAMP AT time ZONE '+08') AS Week, Count(id) AS c1 FROM table_name.A GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1),(SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', TIMESTAMP AT time ZONE '+08') AS Week, Count(id) AS c2 FROM table_name.B GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1);
```